# Set the value by text on x-editable select

Tags: jquery, x-editable

I have a SELECT input with some data. It contains many values and text. I know it is possible to set the current value with `$("#select").editable('setValue', option_id)`, but what if I have no option_id of the the option, is it possible to set the value only with the text value? How can I do it?

Thanks since now

Comment: From the official documentation : `setValue(value, convertStr)` with `convertStr **Boolean** whether to convert value from string to internal format`. There is no `option_id`. Put false instead of an option_id.

Comment: My mistake, do not put false, it is by default on false. Try something like this : `$("#select").editable('setValue', 'Your text value');` (Check that you do have an element with `id="select"`)

Comment: Hi @BabyAzerty, thanks for your answer, but unfortunately it does not work with data-type = SELECT. Works fine with data-type = TEXT. Input of type SELECT needs the ID of the option, not a string value.

Comment: Oh yes ! I forgot that select doesn't work like text ! So you are saying that you want to setValue your select with a new entry that has no id ? Can you give a user case ?